# Drupal 8 Preview button not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-nodes

When using a custom front-end theme, the preview button for my content stops working. It just redirects to the content overview page.

Am I missing something in my theme that allows me to use the 'preview' function?

Comment: Have you looked at your Drupal dblog or your server's error log? Is there anything in there?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have the `?destination=admin/content` in your URL.  This is a core bug.  The current discussion can be read at:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2325463

Answer (score 0):

Jason Ruyle's answer is correct, I had the same problem and solved it by adding this code to my module:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

function my_module_entity_operation_alter(array &$operations, EntityInterface $entity) {
    if (isset($operations['edit']['query'])) {
        unset($operations['edit']['query']['destination']);
    }
    return $operations;
}
```

The code could also be improved to target the right entities, if needed.

Comment: I tried this, the code is being triggered, but it seems to have no effect at all.
Can you explain why this code should fix the issue?

Comment: It's been a bit of time, but what it should do is remove the destination parameter from the edit url in the entity operations (the dropdown/button in the admin content list). The bug should however be fixed now (see status of https://www.drupal.org/node/2325463).